# Rewriting .on methods for jQuery 1.6

Tags: jquery

I want to build in a plugin, which was written with jQuery 1.11 to a site, which was written on jQuery 1.6. The plugin has several methods which goes like

```
document.on('touchstart mousedown ...', function(){...});
```

They should be rewritten for jQuery 1.6.
So how should I rewrite these methods? Unfortunately I could not find any info in the api of jQuery.

Comment: use [.delegate()](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)...or [.bind()](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) based on use case

Comment: What about [jQuery Migrate Plugin](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin)? It could be useful too.

Comment: I tried the migrateplugin, but I had problems with the website than. I will try to rewrite the plugin with delegate andbind methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of:

```
jQuery.fn.on = function() {
    alert('overriden');
};
```

Comment: Ok, but what do u really mean?